# Visual Studio Code debugger does not stop on breakpoint in any other files except index.php

Tags: visual-studio-code, php-8, xdebug-3

I have this xdebug configuration on php8.0 on WSL.

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log=/mnt/c/www/traces/xdebug.log
```

and on launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

The extension used

https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/actions?query=branch:main

Now, When I set breakpoints on `my-root-directory/public/index.php` and run and debug on VScode and refresh on Google Chrome it will stop on the breakpoint.

`my-root-directory/public/index.php` is the entry file when visiting the app on the browser.

But

When I set breakpoints on `my-root-directory/app/controller/someController.php` and run and debug on VSCode and refresh on Google Chrome.

It will not stop in there.

Have you encountered this, and what is your solution?